# Don't restore ViewPager when Activity is restored

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle, fragmentstatepageradapter

The setup of my project is as follows

`Activity` has `Fragment` and it has `ViewPager` with pages supplied by `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

The data displayed by `ViewPager` is fetched from network.

When `Activity` is destroyed and restored, it tries to restore the `Fragment` that was visible in `ViewPager` when the `Activity` was destroyed. But the `Fragment` inside the `ViewPager` tries to access data structures that are not fully initialized, as a result crash happens.

I don't want the `Fragment` in `ViewPager` to be `recreated`.

One way that works is to pass `null` in `super.Oncreate(savedInstance)` of the `Activity`. But it will not allows me to restore state in any of other `Fragments` also which is not what I want.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Why you just don't wont to destroy `fragment` with `ViewPager` or manage data connection `onDetach` or `onDestroyView` in `fragment`?

Comment: As in overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` in the **`Fragment`** and NOT saving state (i.e. not calling super)?

Comment: @xAqweRx "Why you just don't wont to destroy fragment with ViewPager" 

I didn't get that. 

"manage data connection onDetach or onDestroyView in fragment? " It is managed in the parent `Fragment` [direct child of `Activity`] not int the child `Fragment`[part of the `ViewPager`]

Comment: So it means, that you should in parent `Fragment` ( direct child of `Activity` ) -> destroy adapter for `ViewPager` and `onActivityAttach` -> after connection is established -> create new adapter and set it to `ViewPager`

Comment: @dhke no. say page 10 was visible in `viewpager` the `fragment` corresponding to page 10 is populated using data structure which is in inconsistent state, when the `Activity` is restored.

I don't want that `fragment` to be `recreated`. I want that `fragment` to be gone, when `Activity` is destroyed.

Comment: @q126y I am a little confused. If I follow your answer, your hierarchy is Fragment->ViewPager->Fragment(s), isn't it? Which of the fragments are we now talking about? If you don't want the `ViewPager` to save state, tell the view pager not to save state (no re-created page fragments). If you want the whole `ViewPager` created from scratch, tell the outer fragment not to save its state.

Comment: @dhke `your hierarchy is Fragment->ViewPager->Fragment(s), isn't it?` yes. Yes I don't want `viewpager` to `recreate` the `fragment` that was last visible. 

`tell the outer fragment not to save its state. `  pass `null` in its `onsaveInstance`? I will try it. But I don't think it will solve the issue. The `childFragmentManager`  will still have reference to the `Fragment` in `viewpager` and it will try to `recreate` it when `Activity` is created again.

Comment: @xAqweRx I tried that. I set the adapter of `viewpager` to `null` and reset the old adapter to have zero size and called its `notifydatasetChanged` and i did it aggresively in `onstop` to check, but it  still tries to`recreate` the old fragment.

Comment: @q126y that shouldn't happen. The childFragmentManager [gets its information from the (outer) fragment's saved state](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#L1944). So if there is no state ...

Comment: @dhke it seems it shouldn't happen. I tried it is happening. :'( Is there any other reason for it to happen?

Comment: @dhke calling ` super.onSaveInstanceState(null);` inside class that extends `Fragment` does nothing, because the `Fragment.java` implementation  of `onSaveInstanceState` is empty. So I get non `null` `Bundle` in `onCreate` of my `Fragment`

Comment: @q126y Narf, my bad. I didn't read the [code properly](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#L2108), the child fragment manager save gets called after `onSaveInstanceState()`. You probably really have to clear the `PagerAdapter` on detach. I feel dirty.

Comment: @dhkeI tried that. I set the adapter of `viewpager` to `null` and reset the old adapter to have zero size and called its `notifydatasetChanged` and i did it aggresively in `onstop` to check, but it still tries to recreate the old fragment.

Comment: @q126y `onStop()` is too late. The child fragment manager save its state in `onPause()`. One dirty hack that comes to mind is to remove the subparcel with tag `FragmentActivity.FRAGMENTS_TAG` from the restored bundle in `onCreate()` ...

Comment: @dhke That works. `FragmentActivity.FRAGMENTS_TAG` is not public, so value of `FragmentActivity.FRAGMENTS_TAG` needs to be used. And it has to be removed in `Activity` `onCreate` removing it in `Fragment` `onCreate` causes crash. 

If you come across better way to do it. Please let me know. If I come across, I will post it here.

Thanks, for you help :)

Comment: @dhke It causes the `Fragment` to be recreated on orientaion Change also. I ended up doing `setAdapter(null)` in `onPause` and `setAdapter(originalAdapter)` in `onResume`

Comment: @q126y I had a very similar problem about a year ago but without the outer fragment. I ended up completely disabling state restore on the activity. The view is completely data-driven anyway (with data from a backend service), but it still feels kinda ugly not to have a knob *don't save and restore your state*

Comment: @dhke did you do that by passing `null` to `super.onCreate` of `Activity` or removing `FragmentActivity.FRAGMENTS_TAG` from `Bundle. If the latter, what argument did you present in the code review?

Comment: @q126y I pass `null` to `super.onCreate()` based on a runtime flag.

Comment: Try the Kathan Shah answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293118/remove-or-clear-all-fragments-from-viewpager. It worked for me.