# Is the Bundle passed on onCreate to Activity and Child Fragment different?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

Is private copy of`Bundle` is passed to `Fragment` and the parent `Activity`?

I try to save key,value pair in `onSaveInstanceState` of `Fragment` and try to retrieve it in the `onCreate` of Activity. It is absent there.

But there also seems to be a connection between the two.
When I pass `null` to `super.onCreate` of `Activity` the `Bundle` passed to `Fragment`'s `onCreate` is also `null`.

Comment: They are completely different.

Comment: @xAqweRx then when I pass `null` to `super.onCreate` of `Activity` the `Bundle` passed to `Fragment` is also `null`. Why is it so?

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: @xAqweRx It is company code. I can't share it here. Please tell me, which part needs more clarification, I will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bundle` wich is sent to `onCreate` for `Activity` and `Fragment` are completely different. If you're sending `null` to `super.onCreate` -> activity will recreate all the `fragments` from the scratch. So your `Fragment` will receive `null` -> also. Cause this is NEW `fragment`

---

This is a part of code of `FragmentActivity`:

```
/**
 * Perform initialization of all fragments and loaders.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFragments.attachHost(null /*parent*/);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    NonConfigurationInstances nc =
            (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (nc != null) {
        mFragments.restoreLoaderNonConfig(nc.loaders);
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Parcelable p = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG);
        mFragments.restoreAllState(p, nc != null ? nc.fragments : null);

        // Check if there are any pending onActivityResult calls to descendent Fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(NEXT_CANDIDATE_REQUEST_INDEX_TAG)) {
            mNextCandidateRequestIndex =
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(NEXT_CANDIDATE_REQUEST_INDEX_TAG);
            int[] requestCodes = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(ALLOCATED_REQUEST_INDICIES_TAG);
            String[] fragmentWhos = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(REQUEST_FRAGMENT_WHO_TAG);
            if (requestCodes == null || fragmentWhos == null ||
                        requestCodes.length != fragmentWhos.length) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Invalid requestCode mapping in savedInstanceState.");
            } else {
                mPendingFragmentActivityResults = new SparseArrayCompat<>(requestCodes.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < requestCodes.length; i++) {
                    mPendingFragmentActivityResults.put(requestCodes[i], fragmentWhos[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (mPendingFragmentActivityResults == null) {
        mPendingFragmentActivityResults = new SparseArrayCompat<>();
        mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0;
    }

    mFragments.dispatchCreate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to pass `null` because of this http://stackoverflow.com/q/38727802/5455629

Would you be so kind as to look into it and tell how to solve that issue. :)